# I am getting IllegalArgumentException when creating a SparkSession

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using pyspark and jupyter notebook on spark 2.1.0 and python 2.7. I am trying to create a new `SparkSession` using the code below;

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

spark = SparkSession\
    .builder\
    .appName("Bank Service Classifier")\
    .config("spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled","true")\
    .getOrCreate()

sc = SparkContext()
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
```

However, if I am getting the following error;

```
IllegalArgumentException                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-2683a8d0ffcf> in <module>()
      4 from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
      5 
----> 6 spark = SparkSession    .builder    .appName("example-spark")    .config("spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled","true")    .getOrCreate()
      7 
      8 sc = SparkContext()

/srv/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py in getOrCreate(self)
    177                     session = SparkSession(sc)
    178                 for key, value in self._options.items():
--> 179                     session._jsparkSession.sessionState().conf().setConfString(key, value)
    180                 for key, value in self._options.items():
    181                     session.sparkContext._conf.set(key, value)

/srv/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1131         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1132         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1133             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1134 
   1135         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/srv/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     77                 raise QueryExecutionException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
     78             if s.startswith('java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: '):
---> 79                 raise IllegalArgumentException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
     80             raise
     81     return deco

IllegalArgumentException: u"Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState':"
```

How do i fix this?

Comment: You have omitted the most important part of the error log.

Comment: that is the whole error as it is in my notebook

Comment: Ok. Would you care adding some details about your working environment ? Like what kind of notebook ? Your framework version, python version, etc...

Comment: @eliasah I am using a jupyter Notebook with spark 2.1.0 and python 2.7. The only code I have is the one above

Comment: same issue here : did you find a way out ?

Comment: @romain-jouin yes I did, forgot to update. It seems I cannot create a Spark Session when I have one SparkContext. Here is what I used and it has been working;

`from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('app-name').getOrCreate()`

This has been working for me, but only with one Session at a time i.e. I have to close all others first

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same error. Downloading Spark pre-built for Hadoop 2.6 instead of 2.7 worked for me.